# Proving Continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Prove that $$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{{x^{2n}-1}\over x^{2n}+1}$$

is continuous at all points of $\Bbb R$ except $x=\pm1$

Comment: `\lim`, `\infty`, and `\pm` are the codes for $\lim$, $\infty$, and $\pm$, respectively.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, will keep these in mind

Comment: Hint: If $|x|>1$, $x^{2n}$ blows up and the limit is $1$. If $|x|<1$, $x^{2n}\to 0$ and the limit is $-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$|x|<1\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2n}=0$$

$$|x|>1\implies \lim_{n\to\pm\infty} x^{2n}=\infty$$

Now use arithmetic of limits to get (justify!) that the limit function is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\!\!-1&,\;\!-1<x<1\\{}\\\;1&,\;\;|x|>1\\{}\\\;0&,\;\;x=\pm 1\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Note that $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac2{x^{2n}+1}\right)\;,\tag{1}$$ which is a little easier to work with. It’s not hard to check that $f(\pm 1)=0$, and it should be clear that $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, i.e., that $f$ is an even function.

- What is $f(x)$ if $|x|>1$?
- What is $f(x)$ if $-1<x<1$?